# Possible bug when using Azure DevOps release pipeline and Azure Databricks Delta Lake LS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I am running into an issue when I am am trying to promote a pipeline that uses Azure Databricks Delta Lake LS through our Azure DevOps release pipeline.

Our ADF pipeline uses the LS to do a quick look up on a parquet file. This parquet file was created using Databricks. In the LS we have fields for domain and existing cluster id.

[image: Azure Databricks Delta Lake]

When I hit the publish button I notice that in the "ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json" file the only parameter that I can I can see is for the domain.

[image: DeltaLake LS domain parameter]

Thus when this pipeline is promoted through our Azure DevOps release pipeline I have no way of overwriting the cluster value with a cluster that is specific to our tst ADF pipeline.

I then tried to add the parameter in the "overwrite parameter" section by copying the test and then adding the following:

[image: Overwrite ADF parameters]
-AzureDatabricksDeltaLake_properties_typeProperties_clusterId "some cluster"

I made sure to properly add it into the test file in the same format as other overwrite parameter values (ex: S3, SAP BW , and Teradata LS), but I get a warning that because "this parameter is not part of ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json" the release process can be broken. I can then see that the format is out of sync.

So the issue seems like that after I hit "publish" in ADF master repo the domain parameter for AzureDatabricksDeltaLake gets added with no issues, but cluster id does not. I checked the json file and I do see that as one of the possible parameters.

Is there a step that I might be missing? As for Teradata, SAP BW and even S3 I was able to see all the different parameters automatically show up in ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json without having the issue of some of them be missing.

As it stands now the release process does work, but then I have to manually go and update tst and prd ADF pipelines because those values would be overwritten with the dev cluster info.

Has anyone else encountered a similar situation?

Comment: hope you had come across https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/124828/how-to-overite-parameters-for-cicd-pipeline-for-az.html

Answer (score 0):

Just in case there is a solution for this problem and it is not a bug. The issue was that I did not know how to add a parameter to the ARM template in ADF.

One I added the clusterID parameter and published the pipeline I was able to see that in my release pipeline.

A quick way to see how to know what to add to the template parameters is to click on the curly brackets next to your LS. That will show all the possible parameters that this LS would accept.

[image]

Here is the link to the solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/477501/possible-bug-when-using-azure-devops-release-pipel.html#answer-487806